# how can you tell if session cookies are being used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, session

If I'm looking at someone else's rails app, what's the first place to look if I want to know where their sessions are stored - cookies/db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for file -

```
config/initializers/session_store.rb
```

If exists, then look for the line

> `ActionController::Base.session_store = :active_record_store`

or in

```
config/environment.rb
```

look for line

> `config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store`

else default is `cookie store`.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#session for more information.